# Throw Exception based on Exception class name

Tags: java, exception, middleware

I am implementing an object oriented middleware in Java. When invoking a remote call, I will get a response String containing either a value description or an Exception description (Exception class name and message). How can I now throw the respective Exception in my client stub code, knowing only the class name (and the message)?

Comment: Use a regex to identify the class (`Pattern.compile()`) and the error message, then use the reflection to invoke the constructor of the class (`Constructor.newInstance()`) by passing the message as argument.

Comment: It's not a good idea to create instances of exceptions that way. What if the class does not exist or doesn't support the constructor you're expecting? Instead have the middleware throw it's own exception that makes sense in that context.

Comment: It is a requirement to throw the same RuntimeException type that has been thrown by the server's object implementation in the client stub... So I cannot throw custom Exceptions. Regarding to the first comment: I already know the class name and type. Could you further explain the constructor invocation by using the Reflection API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, thanks to the Reflection hint I figured it out. The result looks like this:

```
RuntimeException ex = (RuntimeException) Class.forName(exceptionName).getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(exceptionMessage);
throw ex;
```

`exceptionName` needs to be the Exception's fully qualified class name.